# How should I import python directories with numbers as their name?

Tags: python

I am struggling with importing files into my program stored in a directory named Versions.
The files inside the directory are named 1.0, 1.1. So, how should I import them to use them somewhere else in the program?

I have tried running the import as such:

```
versions = __import__("Versions/1.0")
```

But is this right? Or should I use something like:

```
versions = __import__("Versions.1.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Naming a module `1.0` is going to be a bad idea, since `.` is a special character in module namea, amd also  `__import__(...)` doesn't take file names - it takes module names.

So if `Versions` is a directory which is a package (i.e they have an `__init__.py` file) then you can do

```
versions = _import__("Versions.1")`
```

assuming that Versions/1.py is a valid python file.

So your file structure will be:

```
Versions\
    __init__.py
    1.py
```

If `1` is a directory which will have modules inside it - then the directory structure needs to be:

```
Versions\
    __init__.py
    1\
        __init__.py
        <YourCodeHere>.py
```

In both cases the `__init__.py` file can be blank.

Comment: So I must write the name of the directory as 1?

Comment: @MrigKrafts no - `1` is the name of the `.py` file - when you import `Version.1`, python looks for `Version/1.py`

Comment: The directories are in this order:
Versions -> 1 -> Game.py

Comment: @MrigKrafts - if you want to imporrt `Versons.1` (and not `Versions.1.Game`) then you will need an `__init__.py` file in the `Versions.1` directory.

Comment: I checked it with the first advice that you gave, it is working fine with it. Thanks for helping!!